# How to continuously update random data from server to web client without must manually refresh browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, real-time

I have random data from server and want to send it into web client without refresh the browser.
I use web framework express.js with template engine pug.js, socket.io and jquery.

This is the code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;

var randomNum = Math.random();
var randomNum2 = Math.random();

var data = [
   {
      random1: randomNum,
      random2: randomNum2
   }
]

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   socket.emit('random', data);
});

module.exports = app;
```

routers/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

views/layout.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js")
    script(src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js")
    script(src='js/socket.io.js')
  body
    block content
    script(type='text/javascript').
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io();

        socket.on('connect', onConnect);
        function onConnect() {
            console.log('socket connected');
        }

        socket.on('random', function(data) {
          for(var keys in data) {
            $('#random1').html(`<div>random1: ${data[keys].random1}</div>`);
            $('#random2').html(`<div>random2: ${data[keys].random2}</div>`);
          }
        });
      });
```

views/index.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  #random1
  #random2
```

With all code above, if i run express server then the variable randomNum automatically generate random number and send it using socket.emit to views/layout.pug and passing it to html div.
It works fine but after that nothing changed.

Now i try to use setInterval 5 seconds in app.js

```
// app.js
...

setInterval(() => {
   var randomNum = Math.random();
   var randomNum2 = Math.random();

   var data = [
      {
         random1: randomNum,
         random2: randomNum2
      }
   ]
}, 5000);  

...
```

If i run express server and navigate to web browser, the random number automatically generated for the first time and after that i wait for almost 20 seconds and nothing changed. I must manually refresh the browser to get the value change.

Is there something wrong with setInterval or i put it in the wrong place?

Can someone help me to make the number change automatically without refresh the browser?

Thank you very much.

**Edited**

```
// app.js
...

setInterval(() => {
  var randomNum = Math.random();
  var randomNum2 = Math.random();

  var data = [
      {
          random1: randomNum,
          random2: randomNum2
      }
  ]

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.emit('random', data);
  });
}, 5000);

...
```

Comment: the code you run every 5 seconds doesn't actually change anything anywhere outside that functions ... they're all locally scoped vars ... what did you expect?

Comment: i.e. the `var data` inside the setInterval has zero effect on the argument called data in `socket.emit('random', data);`, and certainly nothing can automagically call the `socket.emit('random', data);` inside the `io.on('connection', (socket) => {` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't just change a different variable called `data` (different scope) and expect a function that is in callback to be executed as if javascript just "knows what you want to do"

Though, your code is close

I think you want something like this

```
var express = require('express');
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;

var randomNum = Math.random();
var randomNum2 = Math.random();

var data = [
   {
      random1: randomNum,
      random2: randomNum2
   }
]

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   socket.emit('random', data); // on connection, everyone gets exactly the same global one-time random data
   setInterval(() => { // every 5 seconds, each client gets different random data
       var randomNum = Math.random();
       var randomNum2 = Math.random();

       var data = [
          {
             random1: randomNum,
             random2: randomNum2
          }
       ]
       socket.emit('random', data);
    }, 5000);  
});
module.exports = app;
```

well, that's sucky code for sure ... unless you want everyone getting the same first random data

```
const express = require('express');
const socket_io = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const io = socket_io();
app.io = io;

io.on('connection', socket => {
    const sendRandomData = () => {
        const random1 = Math.random();
        const random2 = Math.random();

        const data = [{random1,random2}];
        socket.emit('random', data);
    };
   sendRandomData();
   setInterval(sendRandomData, 5000);  
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the setInterval in app.js, this is my typing error. I already edit the code.
I try to use your code above but the result is "ReferenceError: data is not defined".

Comment: well then **your** code would get that too ... this isn't **all your code rewritten** just the `io.on` .. let me rewrite all your code for you