# Javascript - Socket.io - random data generate more if the browser is refreshed

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to send random data from server to web browser using socket.io, the random data successfully sent and it looks to work well. But the problem comes if i try to refresh the browser, i set on the `setInterval` to send random data for 1 second. So the random data was generated 1 array per second, but if i refresh the browser the random data generated more in 1 second.

I used [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) code who has solve my previously problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928261/how-to-continuously-update-random-data-from-server-to-web-client-without-must-ma)

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const socket_io = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const io = socket_io();
app.io = io;    

io.on('connection', socket => {
    const sendRandomData = () => {
        const random1 = Math.random();
        const random2 = Math.random();

        const data = [{random1,random2}];
        socket.emit('random', data);
        console.log(data);
    };
    sendRandomData();
    setInterval(sendRandomData, 1000);  
});

module.exports = app;
```

views/layout.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src='js/socket.io.js')
  body
    block content
    script(type='text/javascript').
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('connect');

        socket.on('random', function(data) {
          // do something
        });
      });
```

This results when running the code above :

```
// normal result without refresh
// generate 3 arrays in 3 seconds (1 array per second)    
[ { random1: 0.3470581717757999, random2: 0.3556736679398742 } ]
[ { random1: 0.06514301754146756, random2: 0.31503780514784774 } ]
[ { random1: 0.23783576682568897, random2: 0.6365470660777426 } ]    

// first browser refresh
// generate 6 arrays in 3 seconds (2 array per second)
[ { random1: 0.45233879122186105, random2: 0.5948030171052519 } ]
[ { random1: 0.5712814090228653, random2: 0.21284004439815907 } ]
[ { random1: 0.12810844234492702, random2: 0.33407477504351646 } ]
[ { random1: 0.15589486794947982, random2: 0.9546592980292927 } ]
[ { random1: 0.7473454659432477, random2: 0.6056724392777655 } ]
[ { random1: 0.711512433048445, random2: 0.13648116937632548 } ]
```

And if i make second refresh the arrays generate faster than first refresh, i can't calculate how many array per second.

How to make if browser is refreshed, the array just still generate 1 array per second?

**Updated**

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const socket_io = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const io = socket_io();
app.io = io;    

var clients = {};
io.on('connection', socket => {
    clients[socket.id] = socket;
    console.log('connected : ' + socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
        delete clients[socket.id]; 
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('disconnected : ' + socket.id);
    });

  const sendRandomData = () => {
      const random1 = Math.random();
      const random2 = Math.random();

      const data = [{random1,random2}];
      socket.emit('random', data);
      console.log(data);
  };
  sendRandomData();
  const interval = setInterval(sendRandomData, 1000);  
});

module.exports = app;
```

views/layout.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src='js/socket.io.js')
  body
    block content
    script(type='text/javascript').
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('connect');

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
          socket.disconnect();
          console.log("client disconnected");
        });

        socket.on('random', function(data) {
          // do something
        });
      });
```

Thank you [Luca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6634591/luca) for updated code, i tried to assign the setInterval to a variable and cancel the interval once disconnected and it works, but if i open another tab or browser at the same time and try to refresh it, the random data generated more array again in 1 second.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Assign the setInterval to a variable and cancel the interval once the client has disconnected (i.e. reloaded the page)

Comment: @Luca thank you for your answer, i tried to assign the setInterval to a variable and cancel the interval once disconnected and it work, but if i open another browser at the same time and try to refresh it, the random data generated more array again in 1 second. I have updated code above.